# How to validate a query in jq 1.5 in macOS/Linux bash?

Tags: bash, error-handling, jq

I am trying my darnedest to figure out how to tell a user of one of my scripts that they passed a query that is invalid per [`jq 1.5`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/).

Here is a simple example JSON:

```
{ "foo": { "bar":"baz" } }
```

I want to be able to present an error message to my user when they provide a query like `.foo.bax` but have it return the value `baz` when they provide a correct query like `.foo.bar`.

I cannot *(or do not know how to)* read `jq`'s return values because I need to run `jq` in a subshell, i.e.:

```
value="$(echo -e "${json}" | jq -r "${query}")"
```

The `jq` always return a `null` string when I give it an invalid query.  But I cannot differentiate that from a value of `null` that might be contained in a JSON file as `"property": "null"`.

It appears `jq` has various functions that I might be able to use for this, but I cannot figure out how I would use them.

So is there any way to get `jq` to validate a query where I can tell the difference between a `null` and a `"null"`?

---

**UPDATE**

What I was hoping to find when I asked the question is a syntax that would be roughly equivalent to `"$(jq.validate("${query}") && echo "valid")"`, assuming `jq` had a `validate()` method.

Comment: Why `echo -e`? It means you're munging your data (changing `{"key": "value\n"}` to no longer be valid JSON, for instance), and is moreover reducing your code's portability (POSIX prohibits implementing any option to `echo` other than `-n` -- even bash won't always support `-e`; it's disabled when `xpg_echo` and `posix` options are both enabled). See [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections, which explicitly suggest using `printf` instead.

Comment: (and while 'echo -n` is explicitly *permitted*, it doesn't have any particular behavior *required* by the POSIX spec, so depending on even that is unwise).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why the `echo -e`?  Well,.. um,... uh,... because I am still learn bash and still learning best practices.  So thanks for pointing out how `-e` will be problematic here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Also, about POSIX, we put a lot of thought into this decision as we have decided to target `Bash v3`.  We are making a CLI tool that can be run both in a dedicated device where we fully control the operating system within the dedicated device which currently uses Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It can also run on a Mac to control the dedicated device.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So given our use-case, unless I am missing something, POSIX compatibility will not ever be an issue for us. By targeting Bash exclusively there are a lot of features that will make development simpler. Unfortunately Apple has stuck with `v3` so we can't use `v4` which would have made our development simpler still.  Alas, it's Apple; What. Can. You. Do?

Comment: One of the points around pointing out POSIXisms is to allow deviations to be intentional rather than habitual. I often use and promote bashisms where they add value and don't add confusion -- but using `echo -e "$string"` rather than `printf '%b\n' "$string"`, or `echo -n "$string"` in place of `printf '%s' "$string"`, is an example of a case where going the bash-only route makes code less portable and less robust but *isn't* adding functionality that wasn't otherwise available.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy great point, thanks for clarifying it. Lots for me to learn still! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a flag in `jq` to propagate the exit code of `jq` to shell which you can use in your command to see if it succeeded.

The official [jq-documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) provides just the right option for this,

> -e / --exit-status:
>
> Sets the exit status of `jq` to `0` if the last output values was neither `false` nor `null`, `1` if the last output value was either `false` or `null`, or `4` if no valid result was ever produced. Normally `jq` exits with `2` if there was any usage problem or system error, `3` if there was a `jq` program compile error, or `0` if the `jq` program ran.

You can see it used as follows:-

```
jsonStr='{"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}'
jq -er '.foo' <<<"$jsonStr"
42
echo $?
0
```

Now for the failure case,

```
jq -er '.foo1' <<<"$jsonStr"
null
echo $?
1
```

Do remember that the above case *would not* be possible if you don't set the `-e` flag because refer to the last line of the above clause

> or `0` if the `jq` program ran

So the error codes are *not* propagated to the shell unless you set the `-e` flag.

(or) a more meaningful shell construct using an if-clause would be to do following,

```
jsonStr='{"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}'

if jq -er '.foo' <<<"$jsonStr" > /dev/null; then
    printf "string contained foo\n"
fi
```

and for the failure case,

```
if jq -er '.foo1' <<<"$jsonStr" > /dev/null; then
    printf "string contained foo\n"
else
    printf "string does not contain foo\n"
fi
```

which if you observe carefully will go to the `else` part for the failure case which is your intention. Without the `-e` flag set, the failure case exit code would still be `0` and the true condition would have been met.

The `>/dev/null` part is just to suppress the `stdout` the command `jq` produces to a null stream.

Also note that the `-e` was introduced only from [jq-1.4](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.4/) onwards.

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed answer; clearly you put a lot of work into it and it is great at explaining how `jq`'s exit status works.

**Unfortunately however it did not address the key aspect of my question, and without that aspect everything else in your answer is moot.**  They key aspect was that I am running `jq` in a subshell e.g. `"$(jq ...)"` and thus cannot access their command codes.

Comment: What I was hoping to find when I asked the question is a syntax that would be roughly equivalent to `"$(jq.validate("${query}") && echo "valid")"`, assuming `jq` had a `validate()` method.

There are numerous workarounds I can come up with, but I wanted to do it elegantly -- and learn more about `jq` methods at the same time -- instead of just hacking a fix.

P.S. I have yet to vote up or down on any answers, so I was not your downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if you use the `-e` option, then the JSON value `false` will also trigger an error condition.

If the goal is to be able to distinguish the JSON value `null` from the JSON string `"null"`,
then please note that that could also be done by NOT using the '-r' option.

If you really need the result as though produced by `jq -r`, then consider first setting the shell variable using `jq "$query"` and
then invoking jq again with the -r option.

Comment: Thanks. That is a great caveat to make, and one that would easily waste a lot of debugging time it no one had ever pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

I (being a jq noob) would validate it like this:

```
query()(
  local q=$1
  local json='{"foo":"bar"}'
  local value=$(jq -r "if($q) then $q else empty end" <<<"$json" 2>/dev/null)
  if ! test -n "$value"; then
    echo "You've done it all wrong"
    return 1
  fi >&2
  echo "$value"
)
```

In action:

`$ query foo
You've done it all wrong
$ query .foo
bar
$ echo $?
0
$ query .foo1
You've done it all wrong
$ echo $?
1`